# How does a Function Reference differ from Action<T>

Tags: c#, delegates

I ran into this situation yesterday and it has been gnawing at me. The compiler does not complain about using a reference to a function for my DoThis method when it calls for an Action which to my understanding is a delegate with a 'void' return type.

What is really going on with this Action parameter on the DoThis function?

```
public class testit
{
    // Call DoThis with just a function reference. Should not work, but does.
    public void DoThisThing1() {
        DoThis(this.thing1);
    }

    // Call DoThis with an action.  This is correct.
    public void DoThisThing2() {
        DoThis(new Action<string, string>(this.thing2));
    }

    private void DoThis(Action<string, string> thing)
    {
        // Do some common things here.

        // Invoke Action
        thing.Invoke("1", "2");

        // Do other things.
    }

    private void thing1(string p1, string p2){}

    private void thing2(string p1, string p2){}
}
```

Comment: What is the question? I'm confused.

Comment: btw, there is no such thing as "a function reference" in C#; `thing1` is a *method group*.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to call the "method group" sorry.  To clarify, I wanted to know why using the method group instead of an action didn't give me a compiler error or warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your question is why this works:

```
DoThis(this.thing1);
```

Then that is implicitly:

```
DoThis(new Action<string,string>(this.thing1));
```

(where the delegate type is inferred from the resolved method signature of `DoThis`)

Simply: the compiler fills in some things for us - syntactic sugar that has existed since C# 2. In C# 1.1, it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for.  I didn't expect the compiler took that much liberty in changing code without notifying you.  It feels to me that DoThis(this.thing1) should be a compiler error because I'm calling it wrong.  I wish this would at least show up in compiler warnings.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Jpirok it didn't *change* anything - it added in some stuff that was completely unambiguous and would just be noise.

Comment: @Jpirok: You're not calling it wrong and there's no ambiguity. Rejoice in the fact that it's several fewer keystrokes.

Comment: Sounds good, so the two ways I'm calling DoThis are both correct and the compiler gives me a way to write cleaner code by allowing me to infer that I want the given method group to be an Action.  Thanks again!